# How does CMake check for a working compiler?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, cmake

When using CMake, I noticed the output messages:

> -- The C compiler identification is GNU
>
> -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
>
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
>
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
>
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
>
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
>
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
>
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
>
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
>
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

I am just curious about how CMake checks if the compiler works and the ABI information.

Comment: Probably the same as `autoconf` does: it starts by running many commands, in particular C compilation with some given sample input. And `cmake` is **free software**, so *get its source code* and *study it* !

Answer (score 10):

You can easily see for yourself. The code is located in CMake modules `CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake`, `CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake` etc.

You can find these modules in `your_cmake_install/share/cmake-2.8/Modules`.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. "Look at the source code" is the programming equivalent of "look at this link". I suspect the question wouldn't have been asked if the asker knew how to look at source code, assuming they hadn't already tried to do that and given up, and when clicking on the question I certainly didn't expect that being a C programmer was a requirement to finding out the answer.

Comment: @Hashim If the question was about solving an actual, concrete problem, I might try to address that particular problem. However, if the OP is "just curious about how CMake checks...", then "see for yourself *here*" is IMO a perfectly valid answer. Furthermore, it's not really "look at source code" in the sense of looking at the source code of CMake itself. It's just literally looking at the CMake commands that CMake executes when doing the compiler detection. So I also don't think it requires C programming knowledge.

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO please can you see my problem here ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60318357/11587528

Comment: So, I tried reading those `.cmake` file and could not "easily see for myself".